# Scoping rules of system command for bash script in shiny

Tags: bash, shiny, system

I want to run bash script each time user click start.  A small example is the following, but it seems the system command cannot run each time user click start button.

## server.R

```R
library(shiny)
library(datasets)

function(input, output) {

    # Return the requested dataset
    datasetInput <- reactive({
        switch(input$dataset,
               "rock" = rock,
               "pressure" = pressure,
               "cars" = cars)
    })

    output$summary <- renderPrint({
        dataset <- datasetInput()
        summary(dataset)
    })


    output$bash <- renderPrint({
        system("./test.sh")
        df_1<-data.table::fread("test.txt")
        df_1
    })
}
```

## ui.R

```R
library(shiny)

fluidPage( 
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Shiny Text"),

    # Sidebar with controls to select a dataset and specify the
    # number of observations to view
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:",
                        choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),
            actionButton("button", "Start")
            ),


        # Show a summary of the dataset and an HTML table with the
        # requested number of observations
        mainPanel(
            verbatimTextOutput("summary"),

            verbatimTextOutput("bash")
        )
    )
)
```

## test.sh

```
date >> test.txt
```

Comment: What does "cannot run" mean? Can you run test.sh manually? (Does it have the execute bit set?) What if you add a [shebang line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87560/does-the-shebang-determine-the-shell-which-runs-the-script) to the top of test.sh?

Comment: Yes, the test.sh can run when I start the app. But I expect the system command can run each time when user click the action button.